# How to invoke a DropDownList onchange event when a form is loaded

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor, model-view-controller

I am displaying a form which allows users to edit or create entries in a `Beer` table. To help with this, the form has a `DropDownList` for the breweries present in the `Brewery` table. When the drop down list selection is changed a list of beers for the newly-selected brewery is displayed alongside the rest of the form by some JavaScript. The drop-down list is created like this:-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedBreweryID, 
                      Model.Breweries,
                      new { @onchange   = "BreweryChanged();", 
                            @class      = "pulldown" })
```

So far, so good. But when the page is initially displayed, a brewery is selected in the pulldown, but since it hasn't changed, the onchange event isn't fired and thus the `BreweryChanged` function isn't called.

Is there any way to get this JavaScript function invoked on the initial page display?

Referring to this list [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) I have tried adding:-

```
@onload = "BreweryChanged();"
```

and

```
@onpageshow = "BreweryChanged();"
```

but these appear to have no effect. (None of the other events look very promising.)

Comment: where have you defined the function ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, the function is in a JavaScript file included in the `_Layout.cshtml` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to a jquery event or javascript onload event to do this, as there is no 'razor' way of doing it right.

user either:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       BreweryChanged();
});
```

OR:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     BreweryChanged();
}, false);
```

Further edit:

The `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'` is called when the DOM of the page is fully loaded and should be the first JS method called. 
It is an event handler, so if you breakpoint in the developer console on `BreweryChanged();`

you should see it's action **right when the content is loaded**

If you breakpoint on:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     BreweryChanged();
}, false);
```

You will see an event attached to the javascript document object. 
use it like this:

```
<script>
  //global vars go here
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
         BreweryChanged();
    }, false);
//rest of your logic and methods
</script>
```

*the `false` states it is not a read only event. you can supply another Boolean, to state if the event is cleanable or not, the default is not.*

Comment: Thank you; the JavaScript method looks promising. Perhaps you could expand a little on that. Where would I put that code and how would I ensure it is invoked?

Comment: This was the perfect solution and a life saver :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Triggering `BreweryChanged()` when document is ready should have the desired effect. You said there is a problem with that, so I'd suggest:

1. Wait for page load
2. Grab the dropdown
3. Set initial value with `.value` despite it being the same - it should trigger the function.